# Creating a custom image widget in Apostrophe CMS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nunjucks, apostrophe-cms

I am having trouble creating a custom image widget in Apostrophe CMS. The current `apostrophe-images-widgets` works fine for more images, but I need a special case for the website logo as it needs specific css and a specific location on the website.

I tried following the tutorial [here](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/reusable-content-with-pieces.html#custom-templates-for-widgets) for making a custom widget with a manager, but I have no gotten the results I would like. Here is my `logo-image` module

```
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
    name: 'logo-image',
    label: 'Website Logo',
    addFields: [
        {
            name: 'companyName',
            label: 'Company Name',
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        {
            name: 'logo',
            label: 'Logo',
            type: 'singleton',
            widgetType: 'apostrophe-images',
            options: {
                limit: 1,
                minSize: [ 200, 200 ]
            }
        }
    ],
    construct: function(self, options) {
        self.beforeSave = function(req, piece, options, callback) {
            piece.companyName = 'Freedom Mutts';
            return callback();
        };
    }
};
```

which I registered in `app.js` like so

```
modules: {
    'logo-image': {}
}
```

Then, I have a `logo-image-widgets` module with an `index.js` like so

```
module.exports = {
      extend: 'apostrophe-pieces-widgets',
      label: 'Website Logo',
      filters: {
          projection: {
          slug: 1,
          title: 1,
          type: 1,
          tags: 1
      }
   }
};
```

and a `modules/logo-image-widgets/views/widget.html` like so

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">{{
  apos.singleton(
    piece,
    'logo',
    'apostrophe-images',
    {
      edit: false
    }
  )
}}</a>
```

and a base layout like so

```
{% extends data.outerLayout %}
<div class="apos-refreshable" data-apos-refreshable>
    {% block beforeMain %}
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top nav-back">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    {{
                        apos.area(data.page, 'logo', {
                            widgets: {
                                'logo-image': {}
                            }
                        })
                    }}
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">Our Pets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><button class="btn header-btn">Donate <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </nav>
    {% endblock %}
    {% block main %}
        Main code here...
    {% endblock %}
    {% block afterMain %}
        layout code here...
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

This leaves me with a couple issues, 1) I cannot add the logo image to the website itself, only through the menu bar and 2) I don't think it is actually what I want. I want a custom `<img />` tag rendered with my own css classes.

I wasn't too sure where to ask this question, so any advice would be great. I am having a lot of trouble creating more complex custom widgets.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the lead developer of Apostrophe at P'unk Avenue.

What you've done here shows a solid grasp of how pieces and pieces-widgets work, although our convention would be to always give the module itself a plural name (it manages many things) while the name property remains singular (it's what we call *one* instance of the thing in the database). That's just a style nitpick though, the code is fine.

The advice you really need: there's a much easier way to get where you're going for a single project. Just copy the `lib/modules/apostrophe-images-widgets/views/widgetBase.html` file of the original `apostrophe-images-widgets` module to the file `lib/modules/apostrophe-images-widgets/views/widget.html` at project level and hack it up to your heart's content.

(You could just copy `widget.html` and override various template blocks in `widgetBase`, but it sounds like your needs wouldn't be met by those blocks alone.)

Since you don't want this behavior change for every single widget, use an `if` statement in your template to vary the output based on `data.options.foo`, where `foo` is any option you're passing to the widget in your home page template. Look at how `data.options.size` is handled now, for instance.

If you need extra JavaScript, copy `lib/modules/apostrophe-images-widgets/public/js/always.js` to project level as well; it's very short, consisting of a `play` method that invokes our `jquery-projector` plugin. Your `play` method can do anything it wants to instead.

Having said that, if your goals are more ambitious, take a look at the `apostrophe-images` and `apostrophe-images-widgets` modules themselves. They use the `attachment` field type, which you can use too, including using it directly in a widget module if you are not interested in having a browseable repository of images for reuse. So you can bypass the "widgets display stuff drawn from a repository of pieces" pattern entirely.

Comment: I have an override for the `apostrophe-images-widgets` `widget.html` in my local project, however I am getting an issue where `apos.attachments.url` is called twice. The second time is with an `undefined` attachment. This is when I select an image to display on the screen from the image selection panel. Any ideas? Any more info I can give?

Comment: How/where would you like it? Do you want a new question, or is there somewhere else I can post the code? A comment may not be fitting. I have no idea where to start looking for this issue, honestly. I tried adding an if statement to my `widget.html` to not render the image if the attachment was undefined but that gave another error. I've been going through the apostrophe git repo with a fine-toothed comb trying to find anything, but that is a daunting and mainly fruitless task in this scenario.

Comment: The operative words here are "I have an override..." I assume this problem only occurs with your custom code, so share that. If there's too much for a stack overflow question, I suggest you fork the apostrophe-sandbox repo and push code to your fork that is sufficient to demo the issue you're having.